# WPF скопировать элемент

Tags: c#, wpf

в коде создаю 2 похожих элемента для канваса:

```
Label tbN = new Label()
{
    Content = cN,
    Width=colWd,
    Height=lblH,
    Foreground=Brushes.White,
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    FontSize=10,
    IsHitTestVisible=false
};

Label tbD = new Label()
{
    Content = cD,
    Height = lblH,
    Width = colWd,
    Foreground = Brushes.White,
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    FontSize = 10,
    IsHitTestVisible = false
};

graphicCanvas.Children.Add(tbN);
graphicCanvas.Children.Add(tbD);
```

хочу упростить и скопировать все свойства из первого лабел и затем изменить в новом контент.  делал так

```
Label tbD=tbN;
tbD.Content="something";
```

На этапе `graphicCanvas.Children.Add(tbD);`
получаю "Указанный элемент Visual уже является дочерним по отношению к другому элементу Visual или корневому элементу CompositionTarget."

как правильно скопировать элемент?

Comment: Почему не используете шаблоны, да и вообще xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так

```
        Label tbN = new Label()
        {
            Content = "MyLabel",
            Width = 150,
            Height = 150,
            Foreground = Brushes.Blue,
            HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
            FontSize = 10,
            IsHitTestVisible = false
        };

        Label lbl2 = XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(tbN)) as Label;
        lbl2.Content = "newLabel";
        lbl2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;

        graphicCanvas.Children.Add(tbN);
        graphicCanvas.Children.Add(lbl2);
```